# consuming a .net web service and nsoperation

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

I am writing an ipad app that's going to list data, including images, from a WS.

I am going to consume a web service written in .net (.asmx). I looked at 2 examples,

- the seismicxml that uses NSOperation and uses an xml feed.
- another awesome example from Wei-Meng Lee that does not use NSOperation but shows how to make the soap envelope and uses an asmx service.

My question: is it better to use NSOperation and threading? 
Or should I just forget about it and go with the simple implementation?

Plz help me, I am confused!

Thanks,
Simone

Comment: hmm.  what is meant by "simple implementation"?  The seismic XML example is fantastic for consuming XML/RSS feeds - but the .  If your looking to consume a SOAP response, you may still want to use the NSOp approach because you'll still be calling a web service and parsing XML which you won't want to do on the main thread.

Comment: Yes, the seismic XML example is good, I just had to change it to consume SOAP and it works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SeismicXML and the LazyTables are good examples that show how to load images from a web service in a UITableView using NSOperation and xmlParser. But the NSURLConnection request is called outside the NSOperation, so I had to modify it a little to suit my purposes. Another good example that I found is the LinkedImageFetcher which shows how to fetch images from a website, and includes NSURLConnection request inside an NSOperation.